# Mocking an object constructed inside a method call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, mstest, rhino-mocks

I'm new to Rhino Mocks and mocking in C# though not in general. I'm writing unit tests for a class `MyClass`which internally creates other objects as private fields. I've unit tested those classes separately but not how `MyClass` interacts with them...

```
class MyClass
{
 public void Method1()
 {
  var o = new OtherClass();
  o.Method2();
  o.Method3();
 }
}
```

Note that I don't pass `OtherClass` as a ctor argument and I don't really want to... creating these objects is something the class does, I don't really want an external agent injecting them.

Does Rhino Mocks allow me to somehow mock `OtherClass` in this scenario from a unit test, so I can determine instances are created and interacted with correctly?

Answer (score 1):

No, Rhinomocks mocks doesn't support this capability. Rhinomocks/Moq/FakeItEasy/NSubstitute are all proxy based tools which means non of them are able to isolate your code without refactoring.

To be able to isolate without refactoring you need to use code weaving tools such as [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page), [Msfakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) and etc...

Somehow it is not so popular in the community to combine 2 mocking frameworks in the same project, however when I was in the .net world I usually combine Rhinomocks and Msfakes together;

- Rhinomocks as a default Mocking framework
- Msfakes only where it is necessary(for regular cases Rhinomocks is better....); static/sealed and etc...

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer I work at TypeMock.

It's very simple to fake a future Instance when using Typemock Isolator, actually it can be done in one line :

```
    var classUnderTest = new MyClass();
    // Faking future OtherClass 
    var fakeOther = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<OtherClass>();
```

And you can read more about it [here](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Ffakingfutureinstances.htm).